# Mojo::UserAgent (Mojo command line ) and insecure modifier

Tags: perl, mojo-useragent

I have the following Mojo::UserAgent code which works fine :

```
$ua->insecure(1)->get('https://someurl')
```

trying to do this with Mojo command line

```
 mojo get -v https://someurl
```

I am getting this error

```
SSL connect attempt failed error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

My question is it possible to make the  `Mojo get` to run as insecure like the `$ua->insecure(1)->get('https://someurl')`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks any research. A simple `mojo get --help` would have provided the answer. And it was so trivial that the OP found the answer themselves within minutes of posting the question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 1) lack of research is not a valid reason to close a post (although I understand the sentiment). 2) I actually think that this is not a bad question. Googling "mojo get insecure" now shows this question as the 1st result, which is likely to help future people with the same problem. Yes, the documentation of Mojolicious::Command::get comes right after in the Google search, but if we closed all questions that can be answers by the doc, we'd really not have much questions left open. Also, the question is clear and well written, and includes all the details that are required.

Comment: Furthermore, one may argue that this question is more focused that the whole documentation of Mojolicious::Command::get, which would make it more useful for someone with the same problem: they won't have to go through the documentation, wonder if `-k` is really the way to go: the answer tells them it is. Finally, Googling for "mojo get" + the error message ("SSL connect attempt...") doesn't show any useful result; now, thanks to this question, it should.

Answer (score 4):

I found it , its `-k` or `--insecure` modifier

for example

`mojo get -v -k https://someurl`